# Coding a time condition together with an action

Tags: java, android, time, conditional-statements

When the app launch, I have a button (`btn1`) and a timer starting (`long start = System.nanoTome();`).

Now, two things can happen:

- either the button is clicked at any time BEFORE the time limit of 1 minute (do some code_A then)
- or the timer (`long elapsedTime = System.nanoTome() - start;`) reaches the time limit of 1 minute (do some code_B then)

I have tried lots of various combinations, but I stuck on the logic with regard to the time dimension and the if/while or whatever loop that would express/trigger BOTH the time condition OR the action condition (button btn1 pressed) in parallel.

Does anybody have an idea? That would be of great help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `CountDownTimer`: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer

```java
        CountDownTimer countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long l) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                codeB();
            }
        }.start();
        Button button = new Button(this);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                countDownTimer.cancel();
                codeA();
            }
        });
```

This will create a timer with the length of 10 seconds and the onTick method is called every 1 second.
`new CountDownTimer(timerLength, tickInterval)`

To further visualize your question in the comments, whether the timer stops or not:

[image: Timer finishing normally.]

In this screenshot, I've let the timer run out. The timer was set to 5 seconds and after 5 seconds `onFinish()` was called, as seen by the message.

[image: Timer finishing prematurely.]

In this screenshot, I've cancelled the timer through the `onClickListener`, as you can see there is no message in the center, thus `onFinish()` hasn't been called.

Comment: But if I click on the button in your code (while the countdown is running), does it work or is the code execution busy in the countdown code part? And if the button code works and executes, does the countdown code stop or is it still active to execute after 10 seconds on onFinish() while codeA() would be running?

Comment: The CountDownTimer runs seperately. So when you click the button the countdown is still ticking **and** your `onClickListener` will fire.
Inside that `onClickListener` the CountDownTimer is stopped with `cancel()`.

Comment: @Sam77 I've edited my answer in hopes of explaining this better.

Comment: My bad, I oversaw that point. Your answer is very elegant. Thank you for the details!

Comment: M0e, I choose your answer that fits perfectly my need. But I also keep the code of @Mariusz which is very good and useful. Many thanks to both of you for your valuable help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use CountDownTimer and handle the state there, then invoke the proper method depending on the state:

Kotlin version:

```kotlin
class MyCountdownTimer: CountDownTimer(60000, 1000) {
    
    private var state: CountdownState = CountdownState.IDLE
    
    override fun onFinish() {
        state = CountdownState.FINISHED
    }

    override fun onTick(p0: Long) {
        if(state == CountdownState.IDLE) {
            state = CountdownState.COUNTING
        }
    }

    fun getState(): CountdownState {
        return state
    }
}

enum class CountdownState {
    IDLE, COUNTING, FINISHED
}
```

And in your code:

```kotlin
val countdownTimer = MyCountdownTimer()
btn1.setOnClickListener {
    countdownTimer.start()
}

btn2.setOnClickListener {
    if(countdownTimer.getState() == State.RUNNING) {
        callMethodWhenRunning()
    } else if (countdownTimer.getState == State.FINISHED) {
        callMethodWhenFinished()
   }
}
```

Java version:

```java
import android.os.CountDownTimer;

public class MyCountdownTimer extends CountDownTimer {
    
    private CountdownState state = CountdownState.IDLE;
    
    public MyCountdownTimer(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long l) {
        if(state == CountdownState.IDLE) {
            state = CountdownState.COUNTING;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        state = CountdownState.FINISHED;
    }
    
    public CountdownState getState() {
        return state;
    }
}

enum  CountdownState {
    IDLE, COUNTING, FINISHED
}
```

and usage:

```java
MyCountdownTimer timer = new MyCountdownTimer(60000, 1000);
btn1.setOnClickListener(view -> {
    timer.start();
});
btn2.setOnClickListener(view -> {
    if(timer.getState() == State.RUNNING) {
        callMethodWhenRunning();
    } else if (timer.getState == State.FINISHED) {
        callMethodWhenFinished();
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I must study your code shortly with regard to my code situation. Could you please provide some java and not kotlin? I do not use kotlin.